# Handling varied-size input with fixed-input network

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I'm running A3C (Asynchronous Actor-Critic Agents) to learn a game where an agent needs to catch 3 rewards. The input of my network, among other things, is the relative position of the 3 rewards against the agent.

However, as the agent catches these rewards, my network can't just decrease its input size. What are ways of handling this?

My current solutions have been:

- set remaining features to zero - have tried, bad results
- just show the closest reward - loss of information, might not be optimal
- repeat existing reward positions to remaining features - we are giving more emphasis to some rewards (the ones that are repeated) over others

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional, binary feature indicating for each reward if it has already been caught?

Comment: @user12889 Great idea, actually, I hadn't thought of that